# Waiting on only one operation in an OperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, macos, operationqueue

When using OperationQueues in Swift, what's the best-practise way to wait until *any* operation in the queue has completed, as opposed to the usual requirement of waiting until all have completed via `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()`?

The motivation is a concurrent search algorithm, in which any one of the search operations has an equal chance of finding the answer, at which point I want to cancel all of the other now-redundant operations which are looking for the same thing.

My initial naive implementation is to pass each operation a reference to the queue to allow the first to finish to call `cancelAllOperations()` on it, resulting in something of the following form:

```
class FindOperation: Operation {
    private weak var queue: OperationQueue?
    private var answerFound = false
    override var isFinished: Bool { answerFound }

    init(queue: OperationQueue) {
        self.queue = queue
    }

    override func start() {
        while(!answerFound && !self.isCancelled) {
            // Do some intensive work to find our answer
        }
        
        // We've found our answer so tell the queue to cancel other
        // operations, which were all looking for the same thing
        queue?.cancelAllOperations()
    }
}

...

let queue = OperationQueue()
let coreCount = ProcessInfo.processInfo.activeProcessorCount
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = coreCount

for _ in 0..<coreCount {
    let findOperation = FindOperation(queue: queue)
    queue.addOperation(findOperation)
}

queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
```

This feels wrong since operations definitely shouldn't need to know about their own queue.

I can find no reference in the `OperationQueue` docs that address this scenario. Is there a nicer way to wait for only one operation to complete?

Comment: why not make whoever schedules the operation to be responsible for cancelling them? I.e. notify the caller when one operation completed; the caller than can call `.cancelAllOperations()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caller can set the [`completionBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1408085-completionblock) for the operations. It keeps all of the code associated with operation queues all in one area in the broader codebase.

```swift
let queue = OperationQueue()

let operations = (0..<count).map { _ in
    let operation = FindOperation()
    operation.completionBlock = { queue.cancelAllOperations() }
    return operation
}

queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: true)
```

Note, I mitigate the race between the adding of the operations and their cancelation by (a) creating all of the operations first; and then (b) adding them to the queue only after the operations (and their respective `completionBlock` closures) have been set.

Also, remember, in synchronous operations, like you have here, one overrides [`main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1407732-main), not `start`. We only override `start` when writing an operation that is, itself, wrapping an asynchronous task (and then, of course, you also need to do all KVO for `isExecuting`, `isFinished`, etc.).

Finally, I’ve set `waitUntilFinished`, because that’s what you’ve done in you code snippet, but one obviously never waits from the main thread. Perhaps you dispatched this entire code block to a background queue, but omitted that from your question?

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you Rob -- and yes the whole thing is off the main thread but omitted that detail.